# View PDF using pdf.js providing its Content not its URL

Tags: html, pdf, web, web-applications, pdf.js

I'm looking for a way to load and view my PDF using pdf.js but I have no idea how to do it providing the PDF's content (base64) and not its URL.

I've got it working with the URL, having it stored around the page loading it. But I won't have it stored as file but with the content saved in a database.

I know it's possible to render images using its content but is it possible to do the same with a PDF?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make it Uint8Array from base64)and you can use it with getDocument (or PDFViewerApplication.open)

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#can-i-specify-a-different-pdf-in-the-default-viewer